# Secondary data disk on Azure VM (Ubuntu 20) is automatically unmounted from time to time

Tags: ubuntu, disk, azure

I have created a virtual machine with Ubuntu 20 OS. It has one OS disk and 128GB secondary data disk (separately purchased) to store all the application data.

I have mounted it on the `/mnt/data` directory. After mounting the disk it is working properly. But from time to time that mount is disappearing.

After restarting the drive, its name is **sda -> sda1** and other times it becomes **sdc -> sdc1.**

I have already updated the `fstab` as follows:

```
/dev/sda1 /mnt/data ext4 defaults 0 2
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Read `man blkid` and use `blkid` to find the UUID (Universally Unique IDentifier) of the partition, read `man fstab` and mount the partition via the `UUID=` specification. For the unmounting problem, look at `sufo journalctl  -b 0 /dev/sda` (or `sdc`).